# React Hooks equivalent of this.setState({name: "halim"},()=>{function(name)})

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to implement a validation function equivalent to that:

```
handleChange(name){
 this.setState({
   [name]: event.target.value
 },()=>{
  validate(this.state[name]) //to assure that the value of name is the most recent
 })
}
validate(name){
 if (name.lenght > 0){
  console.log("name is not empty")
 }
}
```

I couldn't get this to work with react hooks, i tried useEffect but there is not a way to send params to the validate function.

Comment: What does `validate` do? What exactly you want to do? Please describe better what you are trying to do

Comment: I bet you don't even need the callback. Just validate it before setting the state.

Comment: Check this links out: https://upmostly.com/tutorials/form-validation-using-custom-react-hooks

Comment: @Vencovsky I updated the code, take a look

Answer (score 0):

Most probable it's going to be a combination of useState and useEffect.

In your `handleChange` function you set the state with whatever state handler that you want, e.g. `setName(event.target.value);`

And then you have a useEffect, which on the state name change can dispatch your function validate, something like

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (name) {
    validate(name)
  }
}, [name])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the useEffect, useState hooks. UseEffect watches for changes in name and runs when the name is changed. You might want to debounce, wait for the name to be over a certain number letters etc to avoid redundant state changes etc.

```
const [name, setName] = useState('')
useEffect (() => {
  if(!name) return 
  let valid = validate(name) // validate is true or false ?

  if(valid) {
    setName(name)
  } else {
   setName('')
  }
}, [name])
```

Using useReducer hook is also a possibility and validate in the reducer.

Answer (score 0):

in case you are going to keep state structure the same(one large object instead of dozen string values) you can bind `useEffect` to this object since it will be updated:

```
const [form, setData] = useState({});
const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]); 

const onChange = useCallback(
 ({target: {name, value} }) => setData({ [name]: value }), 
 [setData]
)

useEffect(() => {
  setErrors(validate(form));
}, [form, setErrors])
```

Actually `setErrors` and `setData` are not required in dependencies list(see "Notes" section [in docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)). Included them just to highlight the idea.